# Optimal WebView Settings for HTML5 Support?

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm interested in determining what the optimal settings are for a WebView that is intended to show HTML5 content.

Currently I'm using :

```
mWebView.setFocusable(true);
mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
```

With these settings, the WebView score 189 (w/ 1 bonus) on [html5test.com](http://www.html5test.com). I am wondering if there are any settings that I should/could change to get further compatibility with HTML5. Of course, this list is an amalgamation of settings compiled over some months, so I'm also open to being told I'm doing something wrong. I do not have control over the html content to be displayed but am trying to support as broad a swath of HTML5 as possible.

Answer (score 7):

I would add:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // tells page not to open links in android browser and instead open them in this webview
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an (older) project concerned with optimal HTML5 settings:
http://code.google.com/p/html5webview/source/browse/trunk/HTML5WebView/src/org/itri/html5webview/HTML5WebView.java

FYI, normally I also set the database storage path for HTML5:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setDatabasePath("/data/data/" + Actvity.getPackageName() + "/databases/");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also set like

```
try {
  WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
      settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
      settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
      settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
      settings.setAppCacheMaxSize(10 * 1024 * 1024);
      settings.setAppCachePath("");
      settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
      settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
      settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
      settings.setSaveFormData(false);
      settings.setSavePassword(false);
      settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
      // Flash settings
      settings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

      // Geo location settings
      settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
      settings.setGeolocationDatabasePath("/data/data/selendroid");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      SelendroidLogger.error("Error configuring web view", e);
    }
```

Comment: `settings.setRenderPriority()` and `settings.setPluginState()` were both deprecated in API level 18

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the answer probably has much more to do than your Android version than specific settings.

Take a look at the "Tables" section of CanIUse.com:

- http://caniuse.com/

... or MobileHTML5.org:

- http://mobilehtml5.org/

Comment: He is talking about WebView settings he has to done for Android WebView. Check above code.