# Webview links not working with locally stored html file

Tags: java, android

I am currently have a html file that is stored locally, which is just the html for the home page for google currently. When I load the html into the webview it works fine, but none of the links seems to work. For example, when I click the link to navigate to Google images, it tries to navigate to the page,  but says webpage not available. I used a toast to display which url is being opened and the toast shows a url (http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi in the google images example), when I type the url into a browser on my computer it works, but it doesn't work when trying to navigate to it through the webview on my phone. Any ideas? Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView wb = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

    wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    WebSettings settings = wb.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    //Listed as optimal settings for HTML5 (may need testing?).
    //Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097233/optimal-webview-settings-for-  html5-support
    wb.setFocusable(true);
    wb.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    wb.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    wb.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    wb.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wb.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);


    WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient(){
        // you tell the webclient you want to catch when a url is about to load
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        // here you execute an action when the URL you want is about to load
        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    };

    wb.setWebViewClient(client);
    wb.loadUrl("file:///mnt/sdcard/Android/data/output.html");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :-

```
if (!Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
Log.d(TAG, "No SDCARD");
} else {
web_view.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Android/data/output.html");
}
```

or

```
web_view.loadUrl("file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"//Android/data/output.html");
```

and u must have to check below entry on ur **android manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: It was indeed permissions, I completely forgot about it as I'm just getting back into Android. Thanks so much! I'll accept the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: welcome some time also i m doing that kind of mistake it happnd so not to worry now ur problem is resolve !!!