# Webview.loadurl inside @JavascriptInterface will crashes the app

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a webview, which is running on main thread and i am calling webview.loadurl("https://www.google.com")

its loading fine.

webview has following setting, so javascript function call some of native function.

webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, name)

and this class has one method with @JavascriptInterface annotation

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun getTestData(){
**webview.loadURL("https://www.facebook.com")**
}
```

the bold one **webview.loadURL("https://www.facebook.com")** is getting crashed with following error:
java.lang.Throwable: A WebView method was called on thread 'JavaBridge'. All WebView methods must be called on the same thread. (Expected Looper Looper (main, tid 2) {95d9516} called on Looper (JavaBridge, tid 1144) {e018910}, FYI main Looper is Looper (main, tid 2) {95d9516})

I have checked for threads and webview is running on main thread, and while the control comes under the method getTestData(), the thread is javabridge.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run your code in UI thread, JS interfaces are called in some other (looks like)

```
@JavascriptInterface
fun getTestData(){
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        webview.loadURL("https://www.facebook.com")
    }
}
```

from stacktrace:

> All WebView methods must be called on the same thread

and you are creating `WebView` instance always in UI thread (as this is `View`, should be drawn...)

also if you are in `Activity` then you can use [`runOnUiThread{}`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable))

Comment: Not working, nothing is loaded, and no error message. But app is not crashing

Comment: when i put debug to check the error the facebook page loads, i think i need to put some delay to get it work. Let me try it. Thanks

Comment: tried            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                        webView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com")
                    }, 5000)                                      but it wont work

Comment: check out your `WebView`s settings, e.g. like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097233/optimal-webview-settings-for-html5-support) and provide [`WebViewClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient) and [`WebChromeClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient). anyway: crash related to threading is fixed, if you have another issues (after configuring properly `WebView`) post a new question (and attach code which inits `WebView`, its configuration)

Comment: posted new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75171230/webview-loadurl-inside-javascriptinterface-is-not-getting-called

Answer (score -1):

You need to call Android Web view related things on UI thread.

```
webView.post {
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com")
}
```

Comment: did not work, getting same error